# Is there a way to persist cookies or HTML5 localStorage across WebBrowser instances on Windows Phone?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, local-storage

Short version: I have a WebBrowser control hosted in a Windows Phone 8 app.  How can I store values from javascript so that they persist across the user closing and reopening my app?

Long version:

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application that has a single WebBrowser control hosted in a single MainPage.xaml page that lives for the entire life of my app. I created the app with the "Windows Phone HTML5 App" project type when creating the project in Visual Studio 2012.  99% of my application is hosted in web pages (on the internet, not stored on the phone) that I direct the WebBrowser to go to when the app starts up.  In my application's web pages I'm trying to persist data across pages and across sessions.  For example, once the user logs in once then I want to store that on the phone so the next time they start the app they don't have to log in again.

Cookies and HTML5 Local Storage (via window.localStorage.setItem and getItem) both work fine for sharing data across pages in the app while the app is running and even if you switch out of the app (via the Windows phone "hard button") and go back in.  But if the user exits the app by pressing the hard "back" button then the next time the app is started all localStorage and cookies seem to be gone.

Is this the expected behavior?  I guess I'm not sure where WebBrowser would store the data (Isolated Storage?  Or maybe in the same place it's stored if going to the web site with Internet Explorer?).  In any case, if there's no "fix" for this, can anyone the best way for me to provide my own storage mechanism so that I can let my javascript code persist values across instances of my app running?  I'm happy to use the app's Isolated Storage if only I knew of a way to get and retrieve values from it using javascript.  Thank you.

Comment: It turns out that the WebBrowser control **does** correctly store its state between instances of the app. I was causing this problem to occur myself without knowing it because I was calling ClearCache() as part of my application's Refresh button (because without calling ClearCache() the WebBrowser would refresh the page but would not re-download the content). It turns out that calling ClearCache() also removes cookies, so as soon as I stopped calling ClearCache() then everything started working fine. Paul's workaround probably would have worked too but in this case I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is expected behaviour or not.

To get at the Isolated Storage you will need to use JS/.NET interop.

if you want to trigger the persistent storage from JS:

Use `window.external.notify` in JS, generating a JSON string (for instance) to pass along to the .NET side. That could be written to IsolatedStorage without the .NET having to parse the data. You could use `IsolatedStorage.AppSettings` or a full file depending on the size of the data.

Alternately you could trigger the process from .NET:

Call `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` to call a JS function which returns the same JSON string representing your data.

The .NET side could detect and restore this data on startup and use `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` to pass the JSON string back into the WebBrowser via a JS function.

You'd of course have to deal with error cases (attempting to restore bad/corrupt JSON).

Also, if you trigger this from .NET in response to the  `App.Closing` event you need to watch out that you don't take too long writing data.
The faster you run the better, but this definitely needs to be done within 10 seconds or the OS will kill your app.

See MSDN docs for [WebBrowser.InvokeScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.invokescript%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [ScriptNotify registration to window.external.notify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul.  That's a good workaround.  If I don't hear back from anyone about a "fix" for the issue (as in, a way to make WebBrowser persist its internal state) then I'll mark yours as the answer.  I'm still hoping there's a way to make the WebBrowser persist its state because, for example, if a user logs into Facebook and then quits the app then they have to log back in again when they start the app again since Facebook's cookies are gone.

Comment: It turns out that I was inadvertently causing the original problem myself, and didn't need this workaround after all.  But, since I did ask "How can I store values from javascript so that they persist across the user closing and reopening my app?", I'm marking yours as the answer.  Thanks Paul.